# Had anyone tried changing the innodb_page_size of an AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'd like to use a MySQL with a custom Innodb settings. However, after creating an instance, you cannot update its innodb_page_size. If doing it on a server (Ubuntu perse), you will have to set this settings before initializing your db. However, upon creation on RDS, I couldn't find anywhere I could set it.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually edit something like this in a parameter group in AWS RDS. However, innodb_page_size is not a modifiable as the size is directly linked to the instance size of your RDS.